# Is it possible to add an in-line button within a Text()?

Tags: swiftui, string-concatenation

trying to achieve something like tinder's Terms and Conditions, however i cannot figure it out how to make the Terms and Privacy Policy Clickable in swift UI

[image: Terms and conditions Text view screenshot]

By creating an account or logging in, you agree to our **Terms** and **Privacy Policy**

```
var body: some View {
        Text(Constants.privacyText)
        .applyCustomLabelTextProperties(size: size, kerning: 2)
        .foregroundColor(color)
//        .lineLimit(2)
        +
        Text(" ")
        +
        Text(Constants.terms).underline()
            .foregroundColor(color)
//            .onTapGesture {
//                print("test")
//            }
        +
        Text(" and ")
            .foregroundColor(color)
        +
        Text(Constants.privacyPolicy).underline()
            .foregroundColor(color)
    }
}
```

Tried to make a clickable .onTapGesture applied on a Text() and also tried to add a button and concatenate it in the text, no success either.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible currently. I recommend wrapping a UILabel in a UIViewRepresentable.

Comment: also a very good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's already too late, but if this helps someone then I am glad :)

Try this,

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("By creating an account you agree to our ")
            HStack {
                Button(action: { }){ Text("Terms").underline() }
                Text(" and ")
                Button(action: { }){ Text("Privacy Policy").underline()}
            }
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: While this does work here localizing this would be a nightmare and line wrapping won't work on small screens.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can simply use markdown in Text:

```swift
Text(try! AttributedString(markdown: "Please, agree to our [Terms and Conditions](https://apple.com)."))
```

This is the result:

[image: iOS screen with markdown text]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach:

```
 Text("By creating an account you agree to our ")
 Button(action: { self.openPrivacyPage()}){ Text("Privacy Policy")}
  .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
```

You can further style the text and button with font sizes/types etc. Use HStack to keep on same line.

Which results in:

[image: text with inline]

Comment: Thanks @dot3. Not the most elegant solution but for the time being it seems the only way to do it in SwiftUI

Answer (score -1):

Problem is when you have a dynamic text, a whole paragraph that should have a tappable image or text in the middle, not always in the same place.
let us suppose you have a text that is imported dynamically and put in a location on a view. And you want to hi light a single word of interest and make tappable to give meaning or something. I have not yet found away to do this in SwiftUI.

```
let firstHalfOfParagraph = Text($importedStringBeforeWord)
let secondHalfOfParagraph = Text($importedStringAfterWord) 
let word = Text($importedWord)
return firstHalfOfParagraph + word.onTapGesture{print("action")} + secondHalfOfParagraph
```

This never works because word is now AnyView not Text, and it cannot be concatenated with Text! Hence the dilemma.